# How to use "setup.cfg" instead of setup.py with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

It seemed to me, that instead of the whole plethora of named keyword-arguments for
the `distutils.core.setup` function, one can use a `setup.cfg` file in the same directory
as the `setup.py` file and all these keywords will be read from the setup.cfg file.

I thought i could simply create a `setup.cfg` with Python 2.7, but a minimal testing
version just does not work. I did test it with `setup.py --name`, which
just returns: `UNKNOWN`.

And as usual with python-packaging the documentation is confusing as hell,
as it is never clear, which version they relate to or at least how old the 
documentation is.

My two setup files:

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup()
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = foo
version = 0.1
```

I looked into the distutils package and found that (besides being fugly as hell)
it seems to [use the `mail.message_from_file`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/301d62ef5c0b/Lib/distutils/dist.py#l1051) factory to read the `setup.cfg`.

As i am quite ok with a `setup.py`-only approach i would not bother much longer
with such nonsense, but i am still curious how to do it right, if it is possible at all.

Neither the [official packaging doc](http://packaging.python.org) nor the [Packaging-Authority](https://github.com/pypa) seems to be a big help here.

---

*Almost every time i feel compelled to look into python's 2.x stdlib i am wondering if they
try to showcase how not to program. On the other hand the C-Code seems quite beautiful.*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Note that, as of December 2016 and setuptools version 30.3.0, it is possible to put package metadata in setup.cfg, per [idle sign's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41390960).

---

The problem is that the *setup.cfg* file does not do what you want.  It does not provide parameters to the `setup` function.  It is used to supply parameters to the commands that *setup.py* makes available.  You can list the supported commands with **setup.py --help-commands**.  You should see something like:

```
(env) gondolin/zender% ./setup.py --help-commands
Standard commands:
  build             build everything needed to install
  build_py          "build" pure Python modules (copy to build directory)
  .....
  install_data      install data files
  sdist             create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
```

This is the list of sections that you can put in a *setup.cfg* file.  You can list the options that a command supports using **setup.py --help *command***.  For example, the *sdist* command supports the following options:

```
(env) gondolin/zender% ./setup.py --help sdist
Common commands: (see '--help-commands' for more)
....
Options for 'sdist' command:
  --formats         formats for source distribution (comma-separated list)
  --keep-temp (-k)  keep the distribution tree around after creating archive
                    file(s)
  --dist-dir (-d)   directory to put the source distribution archive(s) in
                    [default: dist]
  --help-formats    list available distribution formats
```

You can control what happens when a user runs **./setup.py sdist** in your project by adding a *setup.cfg* file like the following.

```
[sdist]
keep-temp = 1
dist-dir = dist/source
```

So... *setup.cfg* simply configures the behavior of the various setup commands for your project.  The `setup` function really needs to have the metadata supplied to it as keyword parameters.  You could write your own version of the `distutils.dist.Distribution` class that pulls metadata from *setup.cfg* and provide it as the `distclass=` keyword parameter to `setup`.

The missing piece to the puzzle is that the standard `Distribution` class does not provide a way to pass the `path` parameter to the `distutils.dist.DistributionMetadata` initializer which does pretty much what you want - it reads the package information using the email parsing stuff that you mentioned.  What you found is the code that is used to process a [PEP-314](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0314/)/[PEP-345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/) metadata file.  This is not used by the `setup` function.  Instead, it is used to parse the metadata embedded in a distributed package.

Comment: Was there, but it is just not clear, if this is for python 2, python 3 or for both. Furthermore the doc is not complete, essentially the setup.cfg part is lacking, as is the sample project. I just want to use the setup.cfg as (presumably) intended, to replace the keyword-arguments like name, license, etc. for the `distutils.core.setup` function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and your efforts. The issue got on my nerves and i came to the same conclusions. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 33):

I'm glad to say that since [setuptools 30.3.0](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/releases/tag/v30.3.0) (8 Dec 2016) declarative configuration in **setup.cfg** [is available](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/862).

[Documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files).

Comment: Astonishingly, the linked doc does not make clear just how recent this feature is. I spend an hour yesterday trying it out and banging my head why it's not working until I found your answer.

Comment: @DavorCubranic Jason puts changes into Changelog documentation section. Yet it sounds like an idea for documentation improvement.

Comment: @idlesign I guess stdlib's *"New in version X"* got me spoiled.

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer**: The following remarks are true for **python 2.7** with the **stdlib `distutils` package**. They may be **misleading or false for other versions**.

Independently to D. Shawleys very elaborate and sophisticated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077610/1107807) i came to pretty the same conclusions and decided to do a [trivial solution](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de85156a10f0041a9496) for declarative metadatas.

So for the sake of everyone, who got stuck with the same question and does not want to loose to much time on such trivialities here is a short summary for `setup.cfg` issues:

- `setup()` use of `setup.cfg` does not allow to declare name, version, license and similar meta-data for all provided commands, in a general way
- you must use the keyword-arguments of `setup()` to define those meta-datas
- all sections of `setup.cfg` are named after commands and change the behaviour of the `setup()` function [see D.Shawleys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077610/1107807)
- you could define the metadatas in a very redundant way for every command individually
- you are free to use a custom section-name for custom commands. You can use this possibility to implement your own solution, [like i did](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de85156a10f0041a9496).

So with these findings in mind i implemented a [Q&D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick-and-dirty)™ solution which allows a `setup.cfg`-section like:

```
[metadata]
name = foo
version = 0.1
```

and a setup.py with:

```
distutils.core.setup(**metadata_from_setupcfg())
```

Basically i took the distutils2-solution as orientation and avoided the need to do an additional import, with the additional path-hassle in the `setup.py` script, by using `execfile`.

There is an [exemplary gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de85156a10f0041a9496) for the interested available.