# The "version" entry in the metadata of setup.cfg is being ignored

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I wanted to write a new Python package that I want to make available via PyPI.
In the past I always used `setup.py`. But this time I decided to embrace new
best practices of using `setup.cfg`
instead. So I started reading a little bit of the documentation, mainly
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html.

I also decided to use [pyscaffold](https://pypi.org/project/PyScaffold/) for the generation of the files.
*pyscaffold* generated a `setup.cfg` file for me and I added (just for testing
purposes) `version = 5.1.1` in under the `metadata` section, as described in the
documentation above.

For convenience I'm using anaconda and created a new empty environment:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.7
$  pip list
...
PyScaffold                    4.1.1
setuptools                    58.4.0
setuptools-scm                6.3.2
wheel                         0.37.0
```

But when I executed `pip install -e .`, the version was ignored and `pip` assigned a
different one:

```
$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///tmp/test_package
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Installing collected packages: test-package
  Attempting uninstall: test-package
    Found existing installation: test-package 0.0.post1.dev10+g3ed39c8.d20211106
    Uninstalling test-package-0.0.post1.dev10+g3ed39c8.d20211106:
      Successfully uninstalled test-package-0.0.post1.dev10+g3ed39c8.d20211106
  Running setup.py develop for test-package
Successfully installed test-package-0.0.post1.dev1+g228b46c
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077610/1480131 mentions that setuptools version
30.3.0 supports putting metadata in `setup.cfg`, I'm using `58.4.0`, so a much
more recent version.

I also tested with different formats like `version = file:VERSION.txt` but that
didn't help either, `pip` simply ignores the `version` entry.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

I prepared a small git repo with the files in order to be able to reproduce the
error: https://github.com/shaoran/test_package Does anybody get a different
result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `pyscaffold` generated a project that uses [`setuptools-scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) for version detection. When `setuptools-scm` is used, the version is not read from `version` metadata, but parsed from the repository tags. The version `0.0.post1.dev10+g3ed39c8.d20211106` can be read as follows:

- `0.0.post1` - dummy version since you don't have any tags in repo yet;
- `dev10` - you have ten commits that are not included in any version tag (basically the amount of commits you made since tagging last);
- `g3ed39c8` - the short hash of commit you have installed from is `3ed39c8` (prefix `g` means it is a Git repo);
- `d20211106` - `d` means you have installed from a dirty state (some files versioned by Git were modified), the rest is just the timestamp.

If you want to use the version metadata from `setup.cfg` instead, just drop `setuptools-scm` activation in `setup.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        setup()
    except:
        ...
```

You can then also clean up `pyproject.toml`, although this isn't required explicitly:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=46.1.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

If you want to keep using `setuptools-scm` (which IMO is a great tool to prevent you from accidentally releasing dists with same version, but different contents), then just add a new tag to start versioning from:

```
$ git tag -a 5.1.1 -m 'start versioning'
```

If you had a clean repo state (no modified files), `pip install -e .` will install the version 5.1.1 right away. Otherwise, you will get a 5.1.1 with a suffix.

The neat part of using `setuptools-scm` is that the version metadata in `setup.cfg` is ignored, so you don't have to bump it yourself and can safely remove `version = 5.1.1` line.

Comment: Oh I see, that make sense. I will test that later.

Comment: there's one more question I have: how does `setuptools-scm` infer the version when there is no `.git` directory available? For example on a sdist or self made tarball?

Comment: If the repository can't be detected, `setuptools-scm` assumes an unpacked source dist and will check whether a `PKG-INFO` file with the metadata is located in the root dir. If the file is not there, an error will be raised and the installation will fail. So sdists are fine, but self made tarballs without the `.git` index are not per se. However, it's easy to make the custom tarball installable - just run `python setup.py egg_info` and copy `project.egg-info/PKG-INFO` to the root dir.